# missing "@var annotation", Typo3

Tags: php, typo3-6.2.x

I've got a problem with an extension in Typo3. My problem: An uncaught Typo3-Exception:

```
There is no @var annotation for property "enigma" in class "In2\Femanager\Domain\Model\User"
```

The exception is an "InvalidArgumentException" thrown by "...__core/typo3_src-6.2.15/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Validation/ValidatorResolver.php". Looking into the code of Femanager/Domain/Model/User.php, there is a line

```
protected $enigma;
```

but without any

```
/**
* @var $enigma Enigma
*/
```

the variable $enigma is later filled by an object of the type "Enigma". But if I add this part, nothing happens. Anyone got an idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

As per PHP doc for [var](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/var.html) states you need to place the type prior to the variable name.

That is:

```
@var Enigma $engima
```

Not:

```
@var $engima Enigma
```

---

Also; You may need to reload the op-code cache. (OpCache or the like).

Another possible solution is to disable the validation somehow, until your dev can get back it. (Maybe comment it out, seems complicated to predict the full effect but maybe worth a try if the repercussions of being down outweigh the risk)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's still not working. I deleted the cache and changed the line to '@var Enigma $enigma', still the same error :/

Comment: How did you delete the Cache?

Comment: Does that clear the php cache? I do not have much more help for this, if fixing the syntax does not help, than the problem is probably specific to the framework.